# Css text new line issue

Tags: css, paging

Check the image at this link www.checkwebsitedemo.com/paging.jpg
, you will notice part of Next >> is wrapped in 2 lines i.e. >> is showing in 2nd line, I want them to have them in same line always. If the space is less the entire Next button should go to next line but should not break.

Please let me know how can i do this via css. Below is my css code.

```
    .paging {font-size:15px !important; line-height:250%; text-align:center;}
    .paging .paginate, span.inactive, a.current {font-size:12px; margin:1px; padding:3px 5px;}
    .paging span.paginate_dropdown {float:right;}
    .paging span.inactive {background:none !important; border:1px solid #CCCCCC !important; color:#CCCCCC !important; cursor: default;}
    .paging a.paginate {border:1px solid #CCCCCC; color:#0A246A; text-decoration:none;}
    .paging a.paginate:hover {background:#088AD8; border:1px solid #000000; color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000000;}
    .paging a.current {background:#088AD8; border:1px solid #000000; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000000;}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please only use relevant tags for your questions.

Comment: sure buddy, sorry about that, as i am new to stack overflow so i didnt knew that. thanks anyways. will take care of that in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap;` to the button's CSS you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: inline-block;` should get that button to stick together; either stay on the first line or get pushed down together.

Overall, however, you should adjust your styles so that the buttons never get pushed to a second line. Perhaps "..." a couple more pages.